# Extract sub-string from string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, text-extraction

I'm kinda new to regex, so I have the following string:

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (ff108507ea7a3598104c728cc453f299)] -> xpath: /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]] (class: sf-depth-1 menuparent ext sf-with-ul)
```

I want to know how I can remove everything before the `/html`, so I end up with the following string:
    /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]] (class: sf-depth-1 menuparent ext sf-with-ul)

I tried this but without success:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/html.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(absoluteXpath);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Tested here:

https://regexr.com/4gff0

Comment: Why `group(1)`? You have no groups in the pattern.

Comment: Looks like you succeeded according to your link.

Comment: If you want to use regex, you need to create a group in your pattern like this: Pattern.compile("(/html.*)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regex... just use:

```
String str = "[[ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (ff108507ea7a3598104c728cc453f299)] -> xpath: /html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/nav[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]] (class: sf-depth-1 menuparent ext sf-with-ul)";
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("/html"));
```